# can't subscribe or publish to my local mosquitto via a batch file

Tags: batch-file, mqtt, command-prompt, mosquitto

I want to automate the setup of my MQTT broker via batch files, but this code in a Batch file doesn't do anything.

###code for publishing#######

```
@ECHO OFF
cd "C:\program files\mosquitto"
mosquitto_pub -t 'test/topic' -m 'helloWorld'
PAUSE
```

####code for subscribing##################

```
@ECHO OFF
cd "C:\program files\mosquitto"
mosquitto_sub -t topic/test
PAUSE
```

note: if I use these commands in in cmd it works

Comment: "It doesn't do anything" tells me very little. Does the script say that the publishing was successful? Do you get an error? Knowing absolutely nothing about Mosquitto, my first thought is that it's missing some environment variables.

Comment: @SomethingDark the cmd is clear with nothing in it for the sub promt and "press any key" for the publish

Comment: @SomethingDark if it was an cmd I would first have to navigate to the mosquitto folder and then type in the command mosquitto_sub -t topic/test. the same is for publishing only, with a different command

Comment: Straight single-quotes are just normal characters in cmd.exe/batch files, so if you're going to use quotes, you should be using straight double-quotes instead. Also `cd "C:\program files\mosquitto"`, only changes directory, if the currect drive is already `C:`, for that reason you should always use `cd /d` instead, `CD /D "%ProgramFiles%\mosquitto"`. It is important to mention that batch files essentially just enter each line to cmd.exe, in the same way as you enter it directly yourself, _(the only real difference being that standalone `%` characters in a batch file would need to be doubled)_.

Comment: BTW, if `topic/test` and `test/topic` are not supposed to match, and if they are actually paths, then you should probably use Windows backward slashes instead of 'nix forward slashes. Even if your application accepts them as forward slashes, it would likely also accept them as backward slashes e.g. `topic\test`, even if you have to escape them, e.g. `topic\\test`. Also, if those are paths, then as they are not full paths, they will be relative to `C:\Program Files\mosquitto`, as that is your current directory. You must therefore have write permissions to that location.

Comment: @Compo MQTT topics use `/` as a separator and this has nothing to do with file paths or permission.

Comment: Hence the reason I said, "if those are paths" @hardillb. _Had I known, there would have been no mention of "if", but thanks for the info nonetheless_.

Answer (score 2):

First, your topics don't match, you are publishing to `test/topic` and subscribing to `topic/test`.

Secondly, with matching topics the subscribing batch file will need to be started before the publishing instance. This is because you are not using fixed client ids, high QOS and ensuring the subscribing session is started with the clean flag set to false. So the broker will not queue any messages for clients not connected.